# Условие показа страницы

Tags: post, php, get

Здравствуйте.  Подскажите, как должно выглядеть условие, при котором если пользователь перешел на страницу методом POST, то выводилась одна информация, а если переход осуществлялся методом GET, то другая.  Подскажите условие, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть такой массив [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). В нем есть такое поле как: REQUEST_METHOD

Собственно я думаю, можно сделать как-то так:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{ 
   //do something for post request
} 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET")
{
   //do something for get request
}
```